# How do I get grep to keep the file/pipe open?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep

I am trying to debug some errors in a live Merb app.  There are a lot of lined of error code running by, but I jut need to see the first one.  I can use `grep` to select these lines and print them but it closes as soon as it reached the end of the file.

What I would like to do is use grep like the `shift-F` mode in `less` where it will keep the file open and report new matching line as they are written to the log.

`- or -`

Is there a way to do this directly with `less` that I don't know about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
tail -f dev.log | grep '^ERROR:'
```

the -f option to tail tells it to wait for more data when it hits EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this with watch and tail?

```
watch -n 30 "grep 'dev.log' '^ERROR:' | tail -n 30"
```